# Error 1119 when creating "Load Text" button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

A section of a Flash animation I'm creating involves an area where people can write on a notepad, save their work and update it at a later time. The file will be downloaded by users before they run it, rather than from a webpage. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var MyNotes:FileReference = new FileReference()


Save_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, SaveText);

function SaveText(Event:MouseEvent):void {
MyNotes.save(TypeOwn_txt.text, "MyNotes.txt");
}

Load_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, LoadText);

function LoadText(Event:MouseEvent):void {
MyNotes.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
var swfTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Text Files","*.txt; .html;*.htm;*.php");
var allTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("All Files (*.*)","*.*");
MyNotes.browse([swfTypeFilter, allTypeFilter]);
}

function onFileSelected(event:Event):void
{
trace("onFileSelected");
MyNotes.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
MyNotes.load();
}

function onFileLoaded(event:Event):void
{
var fileReference:FileReference=event.target as FileReference;
var data:ByteArray=fileReference["data"];
TypeOwn_txt.text=data.toString();
}
```

The problem is I receive a "Symbol 'Structure Summary', Layer 'Actions', Frame 29, Line 19  1119: Access of possibly undefined property SELECT through a reference with static type flash.events:MouseEvent.
" in regards to the line "MyNotes.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);". I've done some research and understand this is something to do with the parent not being identified as a MovieClip, or something along those lines. I'm still not sure, however I don't have a clue how to proceed! Thanks.

Comment: Just as a note, you should not capitalize member variables like you have with MyNotes. Usually a declaration that starts with a capital is indicative of a class. If MyNotes were say, a class with static members that would be fine but it is just a local variable so you should make it start off with a lower case letter or if you want to get really technical, an underscore followed by lower case letter.

Comment: 1151 should be: "A conflict exists with definition SOMEVAR in namespace internal." meaning that you already have defined that variable somewhere else.

In this case, look for somewhere else that you have typed "var MyNotes".

Comment: Also we're gonna need to see more code or you have to retest, because error 1151 is not the issue you described. It comes from duplicate names existing in the same space. See http://curtismorley.com/2008/05/06/flex-flash-error-1151/

Comment: Guys I'm so sorry - the actual error is, exactly: "Symbol 'Structure Summary', Layer 'Actions', Frame 29, Line 19 1119: Access of possibly undefined property SELECT through a reference with static type flash.events:MouseEvent." So it's an error 1119. I must have been confused with an earlier error I fixed!

Comment: I deleted my answer pending more information. Something isn't right here.

Comment: What information do you need? I'd upload the file but I'm pretty sure I don't have enough privilege. I personally get the feeling the problem is due to the text field being nested in a MovieClip. To quote from the site you posted: "In ActionScript3 the compiler doesn't know what the parent is unless specifically typed or casted instead it chalks everything up to DisplayObjectContainer. This means that it doesn't know that the 'parent' is a MovieClip."

Comment: Okay and I see that, but that doesn't have anything to do with the type of error you've posted. If you can't upload the file, perhaps try uploading it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know the problem is solved, although I really don't know how. I used [this site](http://permadi.com/blog/2010/06/flash-as3-using-filereference-to-load-files-example-for-flash-cs4-and-above/) for a template and worked backwards. I'll put in the working Code below in case it's of use to somebody else.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var myNotes:FileReference;

Load_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onLoadClicked);

function onLoadClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("onBrowse");
    myNotes=new FileReference();
    myNotes.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
    var swfTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Text Files","*.txt; *.html;*.htm;*.php");
    var allTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("All Files (*.*)","*.*");
    myNotes.browse([swfTypeFilter, allTypeFilter]);
}


function onFileSelected(event:Event):void
{
    trace("onFileSelected");

    myNotes.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
    myNotes.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileLoadError);
    myNotes.load(); 
}

function onFileLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    var fileReference:FileReference=event.target as FileReference;
    var data:ByteArray=fileReference["data"];
    textArea.text=data.toString();
    myNotes.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
    myNotes.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileLoadError);
}

function onFileLoadError(event:Event):void
{
    myNotes.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
    myNotes.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileLoadError);

    trace("File load error");
}   

Save_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, SaveText);

function SaveText(Event:MouseEvent):void {
    myNotes=new FileReference();
    myNotes.save(textArea.text, "MyNotes.txt");
}
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed.